# python apply different loops to different parts of the same csv file

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, while-loop

I am a python newbie. I am trying to read a csv file, and uses its info to create 2 different types of objects - "Fruit" and "Vegetables". The general structure of the csv file is as follow:

```
FRUIT
banana, yellow, sweet
orange, orange, sour
VEGETABLE
cabbage, green
spinach, green
```

The "FRUIT" and "VEGETABLE" are title rows. As you can see, "Fruit" object has 3 instance attributes, and "Vegetable" has 2. To apply the right object constructor to the right row, I need to distinguish between rows containing "fruit" and "vegetables". Presently, I am doing so by parsing based on the number of cells with value in each row.

```
from Fruit import *
from Vegetable import *                     # Fruit & Vegetable are Class


def build_object(filename):
    fruit_list = []
    veggie_list = []

    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        for row in reader:
            if len(row) == 3:               # corresponds with FRUIT rows
                f = Fruit(row[0], row[1], row[2])
                fruit_list.append(f)
            elif len(row) == 2:             # corresponds with VEGETABLE rows
                v = Vegetable(row[0], row[1])
                veggie_list.append(v)
    
    return 
        print(fruit_list)
        print(veggie_list)
```

While this code appears to help me achieve what I need for this csv file, it is not useful if, for example, the "cabbage" row also contains 3 cells with value. Example csv file:

```
FRUIT
banana, yellow, sweet
orange, orange, sour
VEGETABLE
no stock, cabbage, green
spinach, green
```

for this example csv file, the row containing cabbage has 3 cells, and will be treated as "Fruit" using my above code. The extra "no stock" is not an attribute, but a sign for a different code to also be applied.

My question is, is there a way to create a **for** or **while** loop that can detect the "FRUIT" title row in the csv file, allowing me to convert each row after that to a "Fruit" objects, and then detect the "VEGETABLE" title row, from which point I can convert subsequent rows into "Vegetable" objects? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Will a row with only one word always be a title? If so, use your same row-length logic to detect which 'section' you are on, then write to that section til the next title appears.

Comment: Are you the one creating the CSV or is this data from somewhere else? Ideally, you would have a Header row for your CSV that would look like:  `food_type`, `name`, `color`, `flavor` -- the "no stock" thing also confounds the consistency of your CSV file.

Comment: @match Thank you, I believe what you suggested is extended to the state machine suggested by AlexanderMP below. I will have a look and see.

Comment: @Pretzel you are right, I just made this csv file for my own learning, so the standard csv format is not followed in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a state machine that remembers what you're reading

```
def is_title(row):
  return len(row) == 1 and row[0].upper() == row[0]

current_entity = None
result = {}
for row in reader:
  if is_title(row):
    current_entity = row[0]
  elif current_entity is not None:
    if current_entity not in result:
      result[current_entity] = []
    result[current_entity].append(row)
  else:
    raise RuntimeError("Row doesn't belong to any entity")
```

The other problem is what you do with the rows that contain extra values. Basically you need to decide which ones belong to what.

This isn't CSV. This is somewhere in-between CSV and maybe some ML that tries to make sense of really bad data, because having preset rules will only get you so far.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I will need some time to understand and test your code out!

Comment: take your time. if there are any questions, ask away, but let me tell ya - you got yourself a pretty nasty data set :)